# How to make doctrine and ZF2 form annotations work together

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to make Doctrine annotations work together with ZF2 Form annotations.

My controller looks like this:

```
namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

//Doctrine Stuff
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use DoctrineORMModule\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    private $entityManager;

    public function getEntityManager() {
        if (!$this->entityManager) {
            $paths = array (
                    realpath ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../Entity' )
            );
            $isDevMode = true;
            // the connection configuration
            $dbParams = array (
                    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'my_password',
                    'dbname' => 'commapp'
            );
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration ( $paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false );
        $this->entityManager = EntityManager::create ( $dbParams, $config );
        }
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    public function updateAction() {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager ();

        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository ( 'Users\Entity\User' );
        $id = $this->params ()->fromRoute ( 'id' );
        $user = $repository->findOneBy (array('id' => $id));

        $builder = new AnnotationBuilder ( $entityManager );
        $form = $builder->createForm ( $user );

        $form->setHydrator ( new DoctrineHydrator ( $entityManager, 'Users\Entity\User' ) );
        $form->bind ( $user ); 

        $send = new Element ( 'send' );
        $send->setValue ( 'Create' ); // submit
        $send->setAttributes ( array ('type' => 'submit' ) );
        $form->add ( $send );

        $view = new ViewModel ();
        $view->setVariable ( 'form', $form );
        $view->setVariable ( 'id', $id );
        return $view;
    }


}
```

and the Entity looks like this:

```
namespace Users\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation as Form;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @Form\Name("user")
 * @Form\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 */
class User
{

    /** 
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @Form\Exclude()
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
     * @Form\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":25}})
     * @Form\Validator({"name":"Regex", "options":{"pattern":"/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,24}$/"}})
     * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Form\Options({"label":"Username:"})
     */
    protected $username;

    /** 
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Email")
     * @Form\Options({"label":"Your email address:"})
     */
    protected $email;

}
```

When I enter the URL commapp/users/index/update/1, I should get the form displayed for the user of ID=1. Instead I get the
`Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException`, 
with message:
`[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Zend\Form\Annotation\Name" in class Users\Entity\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.`

I can't see what I'm doing wrong...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it!

It's necessary to register autoload namespace, since Doctrine uses its own autoload mechanism. I needed to make use of AnnnotationRegistry and its registerAutoloadNamespace method. It accepts the namespace containing annotations (Zend\Form\Annotation) and the base directory of the root namespace (in my case C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\ZF2\library), as its parameters.
More information here: [Doctrine Annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#registering-annotations)

My Entity now looks like this (and works with both Doctrine and Zend Form annotations):

```
namespace Users\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
$pathToZF2Library = __DIR__.'/../../../../../vendor/ZF2/library/';
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('Zend\Form\Annotation', $pathToZF2Library);

/** 
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
* @Annotation\Name("Users") 
*/
class User {

    /** 
    * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Hidden")
    */
    protected $id;

    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
    * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Alnum", "options": {"allowWhiteSpace":"true"}})
    * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options": {"min":"2", "max":"25"}})
    * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Username: "})
    */
    protected $username;

    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Email")
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
    * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"EmailAddress", "options": {"domain":"true"}})
    * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Email: "})
    */
    protected $email;

    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Password")
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
    * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Password: "})
    */
    protected $password;

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```